# no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Graph<int>*’ to ‘Graph<int>&’

Tags: c++

I can't understand the problem I am facing here :

```
class Dijkstra {
public:
  Dijkstra(Graph<T> &graph, bool verbose = false)
    :m_graph(graph), m_verbose(verbose){ }  

    [ .. ]
}

Graph<int> *custom = Graph<int>::custom((int *) &nodes[0], 4, 5);
Dijkstra<int> spt(custom, true);
```

Isn't the Dijkstra constructor taking a reference, and if so, why on earth is the compiler complaining ?

```
graph.cpp:222:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘Dijkstra<int>::Dijkstra(Graph<int>*&, bool)’
       Dijkstra<int> spt(custom, true);
                                     ^
graph.cpp:222:37: note: candidates are:
graph.cpp:128:3: note: Dijkstra<T>::Dijkstra(Graph<T>&, bool) [with T = int]
   Dijkstra(Graph<T> &graph, bool verbose = false)
   ^
graph.cpp:128:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Graph<int>*’ to ‘Graph<int>&’
```

graph.cpp:126:7: note: Dijkstra::Dijkstra(const Dijkstra&)
 class Dijkstra {

I have the feeling I am getting it wrong, all of it.

Comment: Yes, the constructor wants a *reference*. Yet you are passing a *pointer*. You do know that pointer and reference are two completely different things, don't you?

Comment: I love this people on SO, so willing to explain themselves with a river of words. Anyway no, I didn't, otherwise I would not be asking ...

Comment: @pedr0 The _rivers_ are changing constantly ;). Don't try learning the basics of a programming language by asking at SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer and a reference are 2 different things, and in a strong typed language, aren't always compatible. You should look at the doc for more information. Anyway, here is a solution for your case :

```
Graph<int> *custom = Graph<int>::custom((int *) &nodes[0], 4, 5);
Dijkstra<int> spt(&custom, true);
```

Adding & in front of a ref return the address of the object, and so is a pointer.

Comment: Please refrain from answering _off-topic_ questions. This falls into the _simple typo_ close reason category. Also note your answer is wrong actually. What's needed is dereferencing, not an address: `Dijkstra<int> spt(*custom, true);`. Thank you.